# Sql pair latest updates from two tables

Tags: mysql, join

I want to combine two tables in the following manner,

Quotes of SYM_A

```
SYM_A 09:30:00.01     100   23    
SYM_A 09:30:00.05     200   23    
SYM_A 09:30:00.10     100   23.01
```

Quotes of SYM_B

```
SYM_B 09:30:00.02     100   13    
SYM_B 09:30:00.06     200   13   
SYM_B 09:30:00.20     100   13.01
```

I want to have a new table which records the latest quotes of both SYM_A and SYM_B at each quote update from either A or B. The result I want is as follows (position of A and B can be changed, as long as they are on the same row),

```
SYM_A 09:30:00.01     100   23     SYM_B  09:30:00.02    100   13     
SYM_A 09:30:00.05     200   23     SYM_B 09:30:00.02     100   13    
SYM_A 09:30:00.05     200   23     SYM_B 09:30:00.06     200   13         
SYM_A 09:30:00.10     100   23.01  SYM_B 09:30:00.06     200   13       
SYM_A 09:30:00.10     100   23.01  SYM_B 09:30:00.20     100   13.01
```

Currently, my code first gets all the quotes of A and B, i.e.,

```
SYM_A 09:30:00.01     100   23     
SYM_B 09:30:00.02     100   13     
SYM_A 09:30:00.05     200   23     
SYM_B 09:30:00.06     200   13      
SYM_A 09:30:00.10     100   23.01    
SYM_B 09:30:00.20     100   13.01
```

And then does a self join, for each quote of A, the self join will find all the quotes of B before this quote of A, vice versa. Then I find the latest quote of B before the quote of A.

The problem is that since  the quotes table can get quite large, this self join takes too much time than I can tolerate. While this task can be done locally (e.g., in R) by simply passing through the two tables, with linear complexity.

Could you guys please let me know if you have a good idea for this task in SQL?

Much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there is a performant solution to what you're requesting. You need to restrict your requirements to a limited result set in order to get results faster. For example, reducing the number of quotes you retrieve in your first step will increase performance.

Comment: why `SYM_A 09:30:00.01` appears once in your result but the other two `SYM_A` dates appear twice?

Answer (score 0):

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea039/11)

```
SELECT T1.sym, T1.datefield, T1.a, T1.b,
       T2.sym, T2.datefield, T2.a, T2.b
FROM 
    (
      SELECT *, @rLeft := @rLeft + 1 as rn
      FROM (
            SELECT * FROM SYM_A
            UNION 
            SELECT * FROM SYM_B
          ) T
      CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @rLeft := 0 ) r
      ORDER BY datefield   
    ) T1
JOIN    
    (
      SELECT *, @rRight := @rRight + 1 as rn
      FROM (
            SELECT * FROM SYM_A
            UNION 
            SELECT * FROM SYM_B
          ) T
      CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @rRight := 0 ) r
      ORDER BY datefield   
    ) T2
 ON T1.rn = T2.rn + 1    
 OR T1.rn = T2.rn - 1    
WHERE T1.sym = 'SYM_A'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|   sym |   datefield |   a |  b |   sym |   datefield |   a |  b |
|-------|-------------|-----|----|-------|-------------|-----|----|
| SYM_A | 09:30:00.01 | 100 | 23 | SYM_B | 09:30:00.02 | 100 | 13 |
| SYM_A | 09:30:00.05 | 200 | 23 | SYM_B | 09:30:00.02 | 100 | 13 |
| SYM_A | 09:30:00.05 | 200 | 23 | SYM_B | 09:30:00.06 | 200 | 13 |
| SYM_A | 09:30:00.10 | 100 | 23 | SYM_B | 09:30:00.06 | 200 | 13 |
| SYM_A | 09:30:00.10 | 100 | 23 | SYM_B | 09:30:00.20 | 100 | 13 |
```

Comment: This only returns one row? I believe the user is asking for all results/table.

Comment: @hofan41 I finally understood what OP want. Each `SYM_A` with previous and next `SYM_B`